# XPage: Customize/Localize default validation error message (This field is not a valid integer)

Tags: xpages

Is there a internal XPage way to customize/localize the default validation messages like:

```
This field is not a valid integer
```

I was always on assumption that the text depends on the browser language and should display the same thing in different language, however, recently someone pointed out that this ain't true.

Just wanted to understand if there is an XPage way, if not can switch to some other alternative.

Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

Edit 1: Also the extension library control seems to not translate the messages. Just a snapshot for better understanding.
[image]

Comment: Did you install your local "Language pack" for Domino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Language pack on your Domino server. [IBM](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPageLocaleTimezone.htm) states it translates validation messages:

> Similarly if you choose to make a field required and do not provide
>   your own error message, a translated message is provided by the
>   server. The context locale is used to determine which translation of
>   the message is displayed.

Regarding the dialog I have found [this solution](http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_Extension_Library).

Comment: Perfect, that works as intended..however, just 1 more thing..the extension library dialog box still is in English. It doesn't get translated. Is there any special language pack for that? (I will append a snapshot for the same in the question in a min)